# Ionic framework: Generating divs dynamically doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to generate a board game with divs dinamically with angularJs like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="boardgame" ng-repeat="square in board">
    <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.board = [
    {value:"0"}, {value:"0"},
    {value:"0"}, {value:"0"},
];
```

CSS:

```
.boardgame {
    width: 1500px;
    height: 1500px;
}

.square {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    outline: 1px solid;
    float: left;
}
```

I can't see nothing on the screen with this code..
The controller is working good and if I insert the divs only in the HTML file it works...

Some idea?? Thank you!

**EDIT 1:**

With this code in the HTML it works fine:

```
<div class="boardgame">
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>        
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate this _if I insert the divs only in the HTML file it works_ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with your CSS class. Try removing the width and height of the `.boardgame` class. 
And, you can also add `max-width: 100%;` in the outer div class if you have to set the width of the outer div.

Demo here: [codepen link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XjjYqr)

Comment: It is working fine for me. Did you change the _.boardgame_ class like this `.boardgame { max-width: 100%;}`